# Kernel density estimation - application

Tags: distributions, density-function, histogram, kernel-smoothing

What is the validity of using a *kernel density estimation* to *compare model x observed data*?

In other words, if the *KDE* curve for the observed data looks like the *KDE* for the model forecast, can I use this result as a quality measure for the model? If not, why?

In this case, it's a weather forecast model - but I have some complex variables like *wind direction,* for which a simple correlation will not help too much. For example, the wind going from 360 to 5 is a huge numeric decrease, but it's almost the same direction!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do that. Suppose you have a vector of data [-1,0,1] and your model predicts [1,-1,0]. That has the same histogram, but you are off on all points. A marginal predictive improvement of [1,0,-1], where you get the 2nd observation correct, also has the same distribution.

Comment: Yes, i thought about that. But besides this, is there something useful i can take from the KDE's?

Comment: I think the *differences* in KDEs can be useful. I often have data with a big spike at zero and if I don't see that in the model output, I know I am in trouble. Often I like to create bins and make a confusion matrix. If I say the wind was blowing NW, how often did I get it right and if I got it wrong, how? For your wind example, there might be some useful transformation that makes correlation-type measures or confusion matrices more interpretable. Maybe [vector mean direction](http://www.stata.com/meeting/1nasug/cox.pdf)? Perhaps that would make a nice separate question.

Comment: Here's an example of [circular correlation coefficient](http://cnx.org/content/m22974/latest/).

Comment: That's exactly what i'm using by now - the accuracy rate from the 8x8 confusion matrix (1 division at each 45 degree). Thanks for your insights, definitely going to check your refs, and maybe post a separate question later.

Comment: Another good reference is Fisher, N.I. 1993. Statistical Analysis of Circular Data. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press.